# How to efficiently reorganize data frame to datetime entries using Pandas in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, pivot

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I want it to look like this (date index, station columns):

[image]

The names of the stations aren't important, I had to use another file to show a working example.

This first dataframe has columns 0-23 that represent the hours of the day. It also has date and station (locations) information in each row. I need to have the index (or a row) be a date time that combines the hour from the columns and the date from the rows. I need each station to be a column instead of stored in the row.

I used the following code to achieve it, but it takes a very long time to handle even a modest number of rows.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.IndexSlice

df=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(filepath,newfilename)) # get data
df=df[df['POC']==1] #only keep primary intrument at each site
cols=['Site AQS', 'Date (LST)', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
       '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18',
       '19', '20', '21', '22', '23']

df=df[cols] #subset to only relevant columns

df_align1=pd.pivot_table(df,index='Date (LST)',columns=['Site AQS'])  #pivot data to easier view

ozone_df=pd.DataFrame() #create ouput df

for date in df_align1.index:
    for station in df_align1.columns.get_level_values(1):
        for i in df_align1.columns.get_level_values(0):
            ozone_df.loc[pd.to_datetime(date+' '+str(i)+':00'),station]=df_align1.loc[date,idx[i, station]]
```

Here is a link to my sample data so you can test the code I wrote.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Lzl_m_EBCxoBEutl0UP6_TKq6TNgVZI/view?usp=sharing

PS: Sorry for the bad images, I am using a remote computer and I can't get a good screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `melt` and `pivot_table`

```
# setup the initial dataframe
dates = np.repeat(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/03/2018'), 3)
stations = np.tile(['O', 'E', 'L',], 3)
vals = np.random.rand(len(dates),len(cols))
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)
df.insert(0, 'Date', dates)
df.insert(1, 'Station', stations)
```

Melt the dataframe

```
melted = df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'Station'], value_vars=df.columns[2:])
```

Now the data looks like this

```
    Date    Station variable    value
0   2018-01-01  O   0   0.340432
1   2018-01-01  E   0   0.865012
2   2018-01-01  L   0   0.994935
3   2018-01-02  O   0   0.274560
4   2018-01-02  E   0   0.096046
```

Next you need to create the new date column from Date and variable (the former columns 0-23)

```
melted['Date2'] = melted['Date'] + pd.to_timedelta(melted['variable'].astype(int), unit='hours')
```

Finally, create a pivot table with the stations as the columns

```
melted.pivot_table(index='Date2', columns='Station', values='value')
```

Now the data looks like this

```
Station                E           L           O
Date2           
2018-01-01 00:00:00 0.865012    0.994935    0.340432
2018-01-01 01:00:00 0.167927    0.605892    0.271139
2018-01-01 02:00:00 0.314101    0.473481    0.036693
2018-01-01 03:00:00 0.060521    0.462390    0.073077
2018-01-01 04:00:00 0.799032    0.420461    0.52114
```